# Optional型にnilリテラルを代入できる理由について

Tags: swift

Optional型に、nilが代入できる理由は、NilLiteralConvertible プロトコルを実装しているからだと。

var a : Int? = nil
上記のようにnilをオプショナル型に代入するとき、
NilLiteralConvertible のイニシャライザがよばれることで、
nilの代入が可能となるみたいなのですが、
NilLiteralConvertible のイニシャライザの定義が次のようなっています。

```
init(nilLiteral: ())
```

これは、型の指定が、空のタプルにもみえますが、空のタプルは「型」ではないですし、
なぜ、このイニシャライザ呼ばれることになるのでしょうか。
また型の「（）」は何をいみしているのでしょうか？

教えてください。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift言語の中には、1つだけ「型」とその型に含まれる「値」に同じ表記を使うものがあって、それが`()`、型として使う場合の別名は`Void`です。

他言語のvoidの使い方に慣れていると非常に戸惑ってしまうのですが、SwiftではVoid型の変数を宣言して、値を代入できたりなんかもします。

```
var myVoid: Void = ()
```

この(初期値付きの)変数宣言は、次と全く同じものです。

```
var myVoid: () = ()
```

この場合、前半の`()`は型、後半の`()`は値(つまり空tuple)として使われています。

Swiftで、引数なしで値を返さない関数型の表記は、`()->()`、`()->Void`とか`Void->Void`とかいろいろ書かれます(`Void->()`も同じだがあまり見たことがないです)が、全て同じ意味です。

つまり、

```
init(nilLiteral: ())
```

というイニシャライザは

```
init(nilLiteral: Void)
```

と全く同じで、引数として空タプルだけを受け取ることを表しています。

他言語のnullもよく突き詰めて考えると意味不明だったりするのですが、Swiftのnilは「リテラル(Swiftではリテラルには型は無い)で、literal convertibleなメソッドを持つことで、必要な値に変身します」と言うのはわたし的には(他言語よりは)わかりやすいように思うのですが…。

(ご質問の中の1点に答えられていないような気がしたので追記です。)
*なぜ、このイニシャライザ呼ばれることになるのでしょうか。*
引数を持たない関数を呼び出すときに、なぜ空tupleを渡すとこの関数が呼ばれることになるのか、とはあまり考えないのではないかと思います。NilLiteralConvertibleの場合、引数に渡すべき値が無いので「外部名はあるが引数は持たない」イニシャライザを使っているわけです。

Comment: ほぼ理解ができました。「型」とその型に含まれる「値」に同じ表記を使うものがあるというのも理解ができて感謝です。

ただ、「なぜ、このイニシャライザ呼ばれることになるのでしょうか。」
での説明がもう一つ理解ができません。

var a : Int? = nil
var b : Int? = ()

が同じということでしょうか？

Comment: 長い割にわかりにくくてすいません。多分「StringLiteralConvertibleなら元の文字列リテラル(を一時的な表現としてStringに変換したもの)が渡される、IntegerLiteralConvertibleなら整数リテラル(をIntに変換したもの)が渡される」のと同じ感覚で、NilLiteralConvertibleならnil(を何かに変換したもの?)が渡されるはずと思っていらっしゃるのではないでしょうか。文字列や数値などと違ってnilは一種類しかないので、`init(nilLiteral: ())`を呼びさえすれば`nil`が現れたと言うことは伝えられるので、nilというリテラルがNilLiteralConvertibleと解釈できる場所に現れたら`init(nilLiteral: ())`を何も引数を渡さすに呼ぶのだ、と思ってください。引数の場所に`()`(または`Void`)を書くのは、「引数を取らない」と言うことを表しているのです。

Comment: 理解できました。ありがとうございました。